# Dynamic Labels for X axis in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to display the labels on X axis from the JSON data that I am pulling from my API.

but I think we can only give static labels for the axis ?

Can anyone please let me know how to give dymanic labels?
Here is my code:

```js
var obj = data[$("#host").val()].iscsi_lif.result.sectoutput.sect;
   var my_data_list = [];
   var readsize = [];
   for(var key in obj) {
     var avg_latency = parseInt(obj[key].avg_latency);
     var rsize = parseInt(obj['read_size_hist.<=128KB']);
     my_data_list.push('Average Latency', parseInt(avg_latency));
     readsize.push('Read Size',parseInt(rsize));
              
   }



$('#graphcontainer2').highcharts({
    chart: {
     type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
     text: 'Reads Sizing'
    },
    xAxis: {
     type: 'category',
     labels: {
      rotation: -45,
      style: {
       fontSize: '13px',
       fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
      }
     }
    },
    yAxis: {
     min: 0,
     title: {
      text: 'Read Size'
     }
    },
    legend: {
     enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
     pointFormat: 'Read Size: <b>{point.y:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    series: [{
     name: 'Read Size',
     data: my_data_list,
     dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      rotation: -90,
      color: '#FFFFFF',
      align: 'right',
      format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
      y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
      style: {
       fontSize: '13px',
       fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
      }
     }
    }]
   });
```

Comment: Where, in your JSON, labels are stored? There should be something like this:  `my_data_list.push([myLabel, parseInt(avg_latency)]);`, where `myLabel` is category string.

Comment: @PawełFus:
Thanks this works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `category` xAxis type, point formats should include x-value as string, or `name` property. For example, expected input data format is:

```
series: [{   
  data: [ ['Me', 10], ['Myself', 20], ['I', 100] ]
}]
```

Will create three categories on xAxis: `Me` | `Myself` | `I`

So in your code should be something like this:

```
 my_data_list.push([myLabel, parseInt(avg_latency)]);
```

Where `myLabel` is category string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead type:category , use categories in xAxis (if you are not using highstock ,using highcharts)

```
 chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
```

[See working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/p5debep6/5/)